# Which JDKs does jQAssistant support?

Tags: jqassistant

When having followed the [jQAssistant maven instructions](http://jqassistant.org/get-started/), I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> com.buschmais.jqassistant.scm:jqassistant-maven-p lugin:1.0.0:scan (default) on project IPG-parent: Execution default of goal com.
> buschmais.jqassistant.scm:jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.0.0:scan failed:
> Unable to load the mojo 'scan' in the plugin 'com.buschmais.jqassistant.scm:jqassistant-ma ven-plugin:1.0.0' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
>
> **com/buschmais/jqassistant/scm/mave n/ScanMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**
>
> [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
> [ERROR] realm = plugin>com.buschmais.jqassistant.scm:jqassistant-maven-plugin :1.0.0
> [ERROR] strategy =
> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy [ERROR]
> urls[0] => file:/C:/Users/F6IB7WJ/.m2/repository/com/buschmais/jqassistan  t/scm/jqassistant-maven-plugin/1.0.0/jqassistant-maven-plugin-1.0.0.jar

Does this mean, that jQAssistant does not allow me to scan JDK 6.0 projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQAssistant requires Java 7 (or later) to be executed. This is currently not mentioned in the documentation and will be added.

Note that despite this requirement it's still possible to scan byte code of older Java versions.